# The abelianization of $\langle t_1,...,t_n | t_1^2...t_n^2 \rangle$ is $\mathbb{Z}^{n-1} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, abelian-groups, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Hello I want to prove that the abelianization of $G=\langle t_1,...,t_n | t_1^2...t_n^2 \rangle$ is $H=\mathbb{Z}^{n-1} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

In my textbook they display an inverse of the homomorphism $\phi: H \rightarrow G_{\text{ab}}$ defined by  $\phi (a_1,...,a_n)=(a_1 + a_n,...,a_{n-1}+a_n, a_n)$ and conclude.

I proceeded differently and I would like to know if my solution is correct.

**proof attempt:**
Given a word in $m\in G$ we define $\omega_i (m)$ as the sum of the exponents of $t_i$ present in $m$.

For example $w_3(t_3^{-2} t_1t_5t_3^8)=-2+8=6$.

Let $\sigma:G\rightarrow H$ be defined as $\sigma(m)=(w_1(m),...,w_{n-1}(m),[w_{n}(m)]_{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}})$. We see immediatly that $\sigma$ is an homomorphism since when you glue words the $w_i$ will be summed.

Let $q:G\rightarrow G_{\text{ab}}$ be the quotient map. The universal property of abelianization gives a unique map $\psi:G_{\text{ab}}\rightarrow H$ between abelian groups such that $\sigma = \psi \circ q$.

We show that $\psi$ is an isomorphism.

For $x=(a_1,...,a_{n-1},[a_n]_{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}})\in H$ we have $\psi([t_1^{a_1}...t_{n-1}^{a_{n-1}}t_n^{a_n}])=x$ so $\psi$ is surjective.

Now suppose we have $[m]\in \ker \psi$, by moving the first $t_i$ around for $1\leq i \leq n-1$ we have that $[m]=[t_1^0...t_{n-1}^0t_n^{2k}]=[t_n^{2k}]$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Now the relation in the presentation of $G$ gives $[t_n^{2k}]=[t_{n-1}^{-2k}...t_1^{-2k}]$

Hence

\begin{gather}
\psi ([m])=\psi([t_n^{2k}])=\psi([t_{n-1}^{-2k}...t_1^{-2k}])=0
\end{gather}

So $\sigma (t_{n-1}^{-2k}...t_1^{-2k})=0$ thus we get that necessarily $k=0$ by definition of the $\omega_i$.

Consequently $[m]=[e]$ so $\psi$ is also injective.

Therefore $G_{\text{ab}} \cong \mathbb{Z}^{n-1} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You haven't justified that $\sigma$ is a homomorphisms, which is pretty important! You need to prove this. [That said, I don't think picking $H$ and trying to come up with a specific isomorphism is the way to approach this problem. My preferred method here would be to alter the presentation via Tietze transformations so that all but one of the generators has exponent sum $0$ in the relator. For example, your group is isomorphic to the group with presentation $\langle t_1, \ldots, t_n\mid t_1^2\cdots t_{n-1}^2(t_nt_1^{-1}\cdots t_{n-1}^{-1})^2\rangle$.]

Comment: @user1729 yes you're right, I added a little justification on my post (I thought that the fact that it's an homomorphism follows clearly from the definition). I don't really know about the Tietze transformation but I will check it out, thanks you ! And it may not be clear but I didn't pick $H$ it was given.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but surely it is far easier to find the Smith normal form of the matrix $[2 2 \dots 2]$, which is $[2 0 \dots 0]$ giving the result at once.

Comment: When I think about it, $\sigma$ isn't a homomorphism. Suppose otherwise. Then the element $\sigma(t_1^2\cdots t_{n-1}^2)$ is non-trivial, as it is contained in the $\mathbb{Z}^{n-1}$ part. However, as both $\sigma(t_1^2\cdots t_n^2)$ and $\sigma(t_n^2)$ are trivial, we see that $\sigma(t_1^2\cdots t_{n-1}^2)$ is trivial, which is a contradiction.

Comment: And regarding $H$ being given: I understand that it is given, but my point is that trying to find an isomorphism explicitly is often harder than constructing one implicitly, as with both my suggestion on Tietze transformations of @ancientmathematician's suggestion on Smith normal forms (both suggestions are related; one happens before you abelianise while the other happens after).

Comment: @user1729 oh I see I completely neglected the relation in the presentation when building $\sigma$...

Comment: @Julia That's fine and understandable! I've tried to explain in my answer what felt wrong about it, i.e. why $\sigma$ jumped out as wrong. I've also linked to an old answer of mine which explains how to calculate abelianisations of these kinds of groups (rather than replicating all the work in excruciating detail here!).

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun It's a french algebraic topology book, "Topologie algébrique" by Yves Félix and Daniel Tanré.

Comment: Thank you, @Julia :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is flawed because the map $\sigma$ isn't a homomorphism.

Suppose otherwise. Then the element $\sigma(t_1^2\cdots t_{n-1}^2)$ is non-trivial, as it is contained in the $\mathbb{Z}^{n-1}$ part. However, as both $\sigma(t_1^2\cdots t_n^2)$ and $\sigma(t_n^2)$ are trivial, we see that $\sigma(t_1^2\cdots t_n^2)\sigma(t_n^2)^{-1}=\sigma(t_1^2\cdots t_{n-1}^2)$ is trivial, which is a contradiction.

---

Some intuition here: the map $\sigma$ singles out $t_n$ to have order $2$ in the abelianisation. However, $t_n$ is not special and we can define a similar map to make any fixed $t_i$ have order $2$: Define $\sigma_i$ so that $\sigma_i(t_i)$ maps to the element of order $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}^{n-1}\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and for $i\neq j$, $\sigma_i(t_j)$ maps to an infinite-order element. These maps $\sigma_i$ cannot *all* be homomorphisms, as then every generator would have order $2$ in the abelianisation, and yet one is a homomorphism if and only if they all are because no $t_i$ is special (more formally, for all $i, j$ there is an automorphism of your group taking $t_i$ to $t_j$).

---

The answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2888319/10513) explain how to calculate the abelianisation of group given by a one-relator presentation, as is the case here. Using the method in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2888542/10513), you get the presentation $\langle t_1, \ldots, t_n\mid t_1^2\cdots t_{n-1}^2(t_nt_1^{-1}\cdots t_{n-1}^{-1})^2\rangle$, which clearly has the abelianisation you want ($\langle t_1, \ldots, t_n\mid t_n^2\rangle$ as the other $t_i$ cancel).